# Should I return Collection or ImmutableCollection from a method?

Tags: java, api, collections, return-type

When writing an API in Java, returning an immutable collection of some sort, I've got the option of returning `Collection` (or `List`, `Map`, etc) from the method, or guava's `ImmutableCollection` (or `ImmutableList`, `ImmutableMap`, etc):

```
private final ImmutableMap<> _immutableMap = ...

public Collection<T> getValues() {
    return _immutableMap.values();
}
```

or

```
public ImmutableCollection<T> getValues() {
    return _immutableMap.values();
}
```

Which is better?

Setting the return value as `ImmutableCollection` constrains me to use that exact type forever more, so that I can't swap out `_immutableMap` for my own immutable type later on that returns, say, an immutable view of the values that isn`t an ImmutableCollection` (constructing one requires copying the values, and I can't subclass it to provide an immutable view of a mutable collection).

But there is benefit to people calling the method to see the return value is actually immutable, and have the `add` and `remove` methods marked as deprecated, rather than trying to add or remove items and have it fail at runtime.

Generally, I like to return the most-specific interface type from a method, so that I can change the underlying implementation later on if necessary without breaking contract. But there is benefit to callers returning an `ImmutableCollection`, at the cost of constraining future development of the method and causing future possible performance problems due to copying all the values into an `ImmutableCollection` rather than providing an immutable view.

Comment: You could wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableCollection`.

Comment: Several more answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087900/is-it-better-to-return-an-immutablemap-or-a-map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would normally recommend using the more abstract types (`Collection`, `List` etc) in this case.

Reasons:

- It provides more **flexibility** to return a different concrete type in the future. Somebody may come up with a better `ImmutableList` than Guava, for example.
- `Collection`, `List` etc are more **familiar** to users.
- It **avoids a dependency** on Guava in your public API. Avoiding external dependencies is generally good, use the standard APIs wherever you can.

If you are happy to commit to always using Guava collections, or if this is just an internal API that won't be widely used by different people then I guess it doesn't matter so much.

**P.S.** if your concern is signalling to the user that the return value is immutable, I would suggest finding another way to communicate this (annotations, documentation, method naming etc.). The Java type system isn't really designed for communicating arbitrary facts about types (some more sophisticated type systems attempt this, but it's still a research topic)

Comment: 3 years late, but I find the P.S. section is helpful. I've been oblivious to this and tried to commit this particular "sin" a number of times by now. Do you have any *good* pointer on the "sophisticated type systems" and the research topic?

Comment: @tkokasih One example (both as a usable tool and a developing research program) is the [checker framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).  You could use the papers from that group as a jumping off point, or perhaps more generally search for research on static analysis, type inference, and immutability.

Answer (score 1):

> Generally, I like to return the most-specific interface type from a method

You probably mean the least-specific type, because that's what allows you to exchange the concrete result type by something more specific.

In general, if you want to remain open like this you have to look for the best suited common ancestor of the types you have in mind, then walk all the way up to the root until you think it is no longer suited for your method's return type.

Let's make this example concrete with your two classes:

`ImmutableCollection extends Collection extends Iterable extends Object`

and

`List extends Collection extends Iterable extends Object`

Clearly, your common ancestor is `Collection`, so you must ask yourself the following question:

> Would it be ok, if my callers got a `Collection` back instead of `ImmutableCollection`?

I guess it would be fine, as they are already assuming a collection anyways. So let's say you write it with `Collection<T>` as return type. It is easy to see, that you can now simply switch the implementation to an non-modifable java.util.List, without any client code needing a change.

You do indeed lose some information as you pointed out by not knowing from the type, whether your `Collection` can be modified or not. But, this is a kind of red herring really, because if you open up the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) f.ex. of the `add` method you can easily read:

> Throws:
>
> UnsupportedOperationException - if the add operation is not supported
>   by this collection

Therefore, while one can no longer see from the type itself, that the collection is immutable, you also do not have a type that clearly says it is mutable. In other words, `Collection` can be read as *handle with care* either way.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you're returning a (presumably defensively copied) collection then modifying it *is perfectly valid*. If client code does that then there's no problem. If modifying that collection is what they want to do, then you can't be sure everybody will copy it just in case it becomes immutable in future. Public interface changes like this are *breaking*, and should be reserved for major version number increments if they're even done at all.

Comment: Well I agree that the change as such is breaking, but keep in mind that the actual public interface did not change. This is simply a problem of the limited type system not being able to distinguish modifiable and unmodifiable lists (in contrast to s.th. like Scala, where such a change would also require an interface change). All I'm saying is that if you `add` to a collection and it no longer works, you are no more in a position to blame the interface than when you expect a `List` to give you constant-time random access.

Comment: While I agree it's a failure of the type system (Seriously, Java? You have methods *documented to be fallible*? Nice job on LSP, there.) if you're returning a collection and it behaves in some way people are gonna use it for that. Documentation is no replacement for cold, hard, compile-time assurances and some people just ain't gonna read your docs, making it unfortunately a breaking change. Consistently imperfect > inconsistently perfect in cases like these, IMO.

Comment: At least for in-house usage tests should save you from breaking things in production.. if the API is used outside, well you're gonna have to die one death, as I'm afraid there's no silver bullet.

Comment: I don't see there being a huge issue with returning a defensively copied mutable array. It doesn't get the point across as well as an immutable one would, but your API is still valid and strong. If you're making *other* breaking changes too, then go for it, but standalone this seems like one of those times when "the perfect is the enemy of the good".

Comment: @Phoshi: If a base class includes methods `canSetFoo` and `setFoo`, and documents that code must only call `setFoo` if `canSetFoo` returns true, then derived classes whose `canSetFoo` method returns false need not support `setFoo`, any more than a collection whose `size` returns 12 would be required to honor a request to return the 592nd item [a collection whose `size` returns 673 would, of course, be expected to honor a request for the 592nd item].

Comment: @Phoshi: The Java type system is deficient in many ways which make it impossible for code to know when defensive copying is required.  If only one reference exists to an object, and that reference will be abandoned as soon as a defensive copy is made, the copy operation could be skipped without affecting code semantics.  While it is in general not possible to identify all the cases in which code holds the only extant reference to an object, *many* such cases could be identified easily if the type system were set up to do so.

Comment: @supercat: IMO a "canSetFoo" method returning false is exactly the wrong way to go. It isn't something you can check at compiletime, so can't leverage the type system to avoid bugs; it puts more work onto the call site of your API, and forces this work to be duplicated at every place your API is used; you lose the ability to create ad-hoc polymorphic functions and have any strength in the assertion they'll work so long as the compiletime guarantees are met, so on. It is "a" solution, but I would not call it a good solution.

Comment: @Phoshi: Even if a base class includes `canSetFoo`, that would in no way prevent all mutable types from inheriting the base via an intermediate abstract class `MutableFoo` and gaining compile-time checking that way in cases where it was helpful.  Problems arise, though, if there are many different combinations of things which different implementations of a type will and will not be able to do.  Problems may also arise when passing an object through layers of code which knows nothing about their extended abilities.

Comment: @Phoshi: Reliance upon `canXXX` methods is a bit of a smell, but `if (it.canBlorg()) it.Blorg(); else ...` method seems cleaner than `if (it instanceof Blorger) ((Blorger)it).Blorg(); else ...`, and is probably more practical than having a method which needs to `Florg`, `Blorg`, and `Morg` something take a parameter of type `BlorgerAndFlorgerAndMorger` (an interface which extends `Blorger`, `Florger`, and `Morger`).

Comment: @supercat: Runtime typechecks are always awful, but there's no reason why that can't be achieved with ad hoc polymorphism in languages with sane type systems, or the generics system in Java. You can constrain on multiple interfaces even there, making the composite interface type unnecessary (unless it adds significantly to readability). `it.Blorg()` with hard, unshakable compile time assurance of success is cleaner than any of those, and I see no reason why that should not be done! In the case of Foo/MutableFoo there's no reason why canSetFoo then has to exist anyway.

Comment: @Phoshi: Is there any way in Java to represent a collection of things which are known to all implement non-related interfaces Foo and Bar (and whose contents may be passed to methods with Foo and Bar constraints) but may not have share any single common supertype which does so?

Comment: @supercat: Kinda, but it's a bit awkward. In a generic type, you can constrain on <T extends K&L> where K and L are potentially unrelated types. Java's type system isn't powerful enough to represent that kind of union type, though, which essentially means you can't maintain the union constraint outside of parametrized classes.

Comment: @Phoshi: Can one define a `Collection<K&L>`, or if one has a `Collection<K>` and one knows all items extend `k&L` could one cast it in such fashion that it can be passed to something constrained as `T extends K&L`?

Comment: @supercat: Nope. You can have a Collection<T> where `T extends K&L`, but if you do anything to make it a Collection<K> you can no longer be certain everything in it is also an L. You can't make a type Collection<K&L> directly, only as part of a parameterised type with constraints. It's a bit awkward.

Comment: @Phoshi: The same difficulty exists in .NET; in .NET, however, the difficulty is "real" at run-time because a generic method `Foo<T>(T param) where T:foo,bar;` behaves as a family of methods, one for each `T`, and the run-time needs to know which one to call.  Because Java uses type erasure, it would seem there should be some way to call a method which has a constrained type parameter and tell the compiler "trust me".

Comment: @supercat: Well, I'm sure you can achieve it with sufficient application of reflection, but that's neither elegant or clean. The language itself simply lacks the constructs to do it natively.

Comment: @Phoshi: At minimum, I would expect one could do it with `@unchecked`; perhaps that's the only non-Reflection way, but it would seem less evil than Reflection (which would throw all checking out the window)

Comment: @supercat: Oh, if you know your object is of type K and L, then you can cast to K or cast to L, but those K and L types must then be concrete. What I mean is that there's very little you can do to stick it back into the generic type system once you give it a set type. The type "T" is an ephemeral supertype which vanishes as soon as you give an instance a real type, and you can't cast it back. If you know what K and L are, you can hack something together, but you can't do that generically, unfortunately.